# Private Docker-Registry with GitLab

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

I want to have a GitLab-Registry (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/container_registry.html). It is a Docker-Registry and GitLab will handle the Authentication.

My problem is that it is not working and I have no idea what to do.

My Registry-Container is started like this:

```
 sudo docker run -d \
 -e REGISTRY_LOG_LEVEL=debug \
 -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY=/registry \
 -e REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_REALM=https://gitlab.***.com/jwt/auth \
 -e REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_SERVICE=container_registry \
 -e REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ISSUER=gitlab-issuer \
 -e REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ROOTCERTBUNDLE=/root/certs/registry.pub \
 -e REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_AUTOREDIRECT=true \
 -v /home/git/gitlab/ssl/:/root/certs/ \
 -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2
```

My Configuration of GitLab looks like this (GitLab is not running in a Docker-Container and it is installed from source):

```
registry:
    enabled: true
    host: registry.***.com
    port: 443
    api_url: https://registry.***.com/ 
    cert: /home/git/gitlab/ssl/registry.pub
    key: /home/git/gitlab/ssl/registry.priv
    #path: /path/data
    issuer: gitlab-issuer
```

When I want to login with

```
docker login registry.***.com:443
```

it returns following:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.***.com/v2/: error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character 'p' after top-level     value: "404 page not found\n"
```

docker logs of `registry` returns:

```
GET /auth/token?    account=****&client_id=docker&offline_token=true&service=container_registry HTTP/1.0 404
```

Did I miss any part or what did I wrong?

Comment: I faced similar issues trying to get a registry linked with gitlab behind Traefik reverse proxy using this docker-compose file https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/blob/master/docs/container_registry.md Could you provide an example of working docker commands or compose file to do this ?

Comment: How did you generate the public / private key??? I cannot find this documented anywhere

Comment: @Marcel: This is the private-key from your SSL-Cert. (Maybe you use letsencrypt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to set `REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_AUTOREDIRECT` to `false`. The registry then returned the correct url.

At the moment the `REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_AUTOREDIRECT` parameter is not documented.